# Windows taskbar in Parallels VM

Tags: windows, dock, window-manager

I'm running Windows 7 in Coherance mode in Parrellels desktop, and have the task bar visible at the bottom of the screen.

[image]
Is it possible to move the task bar down, behind the Mac Dock, without turning on Dock hiding?

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot, because the dock tells the window server to reduce the windows max height to : screen height - dock current unmagnified size.

So the taskbar (which is in a window), is automatically placed on top on the dock.